# setCharAt method not working as expected inside for loop (Java)

Tags: java, string, stack

I am trying to develop a method to reverse the vowels in a string. For this, I have developed my own small stack. I am iterating backwards through the string twice, once to populate the stack with each vowel I locate, the second time to replace the vowel with the vowel stored at the top of the stack. I have added a bunch of print statements to determine where this is failing and it seems to be failing at the `setCharAt` method. For testing purposes, I provide a string `aeiou` and I am expecting to get back `uoiea`. The chars are getting replaced during each iteration, but unfortunately, they don't stay that way. As of the next iteration, the chars that were replaced on the previous iteration return to what they were before. As a result, I am getting back `ueiou`, where only the first character in the string is as expected (and the third which is a noop). Here is my code. Any tips are appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Solution {

    static String result;

    static class StackOfVowels {
        static Node top;

        public StackOfVowels() {
            Node top = null;
        }

        static class Node {
            Node next = null; 
            char vowel = '\0';
            Node(char value) {
                this.vowel = value;
            }
        }

        public void push(char item) {
            Node node = new Node(item);
            if (top == null) {
                top = node;
            }
            else { 
                node.next = top;
                top = node;
            }
        }

        public char top() {
            if (top == null) throw new EmptyStackException();
            return top.vowel; 
        }

        public void pop() {
            int result = -1;
            if (top != null) {
                result = top.vowel;
                top = top.next;
            }
        }
    }

    public static String reverseVowels(String s) {

        StackOfVowels stackOfVowels = new StackOfVowels();

        for(int i = s.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
            char c = s.charAt(i);
            if ((c == 'a') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'i') || (c == 'o') || (c == 'u')) {
                System.out.println("Initial sequence of iterations identified vowel: " + c);
                stackOfVowels.push(c);
                System.out.println("Pushed to stack, current top is: " + stackOfVowels.top());
            }
        }

        for(int j = s.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
            char b = s.charAt(j);
            if ((b == 'a') || (b == 'e') || (b == 'i') || (b == 'o') || (b == 'u')) {
                System.out.println("Second sequence of iterations identified vowel: " + b);
                StringBuilder newstr = new StringBuilder(s);
                char d = stackOfVowels.top();
                System.out.println("Variable d set to top of: " + stackOfVowels.top());
                newstr.setCharAt(j, d);
                result = newstr.toString();
                System.out.println("Here is the new string: " + result);
                stackOfVowels.pop();
                System.out.println("Stack was popped");
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "aeiou";
        reverseVowels(s);
        System.out.println("Final result: " + result);
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe get rid of the static `result` and use the value that is returned from the method - if that does not work, then try debugger it

Comment: Thank you for the idea. My print statements tell me that it is the result inside the second for loop that is wrong, this then gets returned at the end also wrong.

Comment: Each time round the loop you do `new StringBuilder(s)`, which basically resets you back to the initial string, so only your last change will stick. Move that outside the loop and it should work better.

Comment: why is `StringBuilder newstr = new StringBuilder(s);` in you loop?

Comment: I think that's it. Unfortunately, I have lost a lot of reputation asking this question so cannot upvote anything anymore lol

Comment: Still doesn't pass LeetCode though. :(

Comment: Other things I notice `public StackOfVowels() {
            Node top = null;
        }` is meaningless.  `public void pop() {
            int result = -1;` what is the use of `result`?

Comment: @ehmon I suggest that you accept one of the below answers

Comment: @Scary Wombat sorry for the delay, you are right, I just didn't have time to try all of these suggestions yet. It's hard for me to decide.....I will do this though! Let me think about this a little more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight improvement (debatable) on @Elliot answer is to create the `StringBuilder` with the original `String` and only replace when necessary

```
    String vowels = new StringBuilder(s.replaceAll("[^AEIOUaeiou]", ""))
            .reverse().toString();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s);
    for (int i = 0, p = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        switch (Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i))) {
        // Note that these fall-through...
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            sb.setCharAt(i, vowels.charAt(p++));
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 2):

You generate always a new StringBuilder in your second loop with `StringBuilder newstr = new StringBuilder(s);`
But you always use ´s´ and not ´result´ to build your new StringBuilder.

It would be better anyways to not create a new Object of StringBuilder in each Iteration.

Also it is confusing that your methode has a return value, which is never used.

Following methode should work:

```
public static String reverseVowels(String s) {

    StackOfVowels stackOfVowels = new StackOfVowels();

    for(int i = s.length()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if ((c == 'a') || (c == 'e') || (c == 'i') || (c == 'o') || (c == 'u')) {
            System.out.println("Initial sequence of iterations identified vowel: " + c);
            stackOfVowels.push(c);
            System.out.println("Pushed to stack, current top is: " + stackOfVowels.top());
        }
    }
    StringBuilder result_builder = new StringBuilder(s);
    for(int j = s.length()-1; j >= 0; j--) {
        char b = s.charAt(j);

        if ((b == 'a') || (b == 'e') || (b == 'i') || (b == 'o') || (b == 'u')) {
            System.out.println("Second sequence of iterations identified vowel: " + b);
            char d = stackOfVowels.top();
            System.out.println("Variable d set to top of: " + stackOfVowels.top());
            result_builder.setCharAt(j, d);
            stackOfVowels.pop();
            System.out.println("Stack was popped");
        }
    }
    result = result_builder.toString();
    return result_builder.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would approach the problem a little differently, first I would use a *regular expression* to remove all consonants from the `String` to create a `String` of `vowels`. Then I would iterate through the characters of the `String`, using `StringBuilder` to build the output (passing consonants through, but replacing vowels using the `vowels` `String` previously created). Like,

```
public static String reverseVowels(String s) {
    // Match all consonants, and remove them. Reverse that String.
    String vowels = new StringBuilder(s.replaceAll("[^AEIOUaeiou]", ""))
            .reverse().toString();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0, p = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        switch (Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i))) {
        // Note that these fall-through...
        case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
            sb.append(vowels.charAt(p++));
            break;
        default:
            sb.append(s.charAt(i));
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This is one of the places that `switch` and fall-through behavior can be taken advantage of.

And if you're using Java 8+, you could express the same with an `IntStream` and map the characters; like

```
String vowels = new StringBuilder(s.replaceAll("[^AEIOUaeiou]", ""))
        .reverse().toString();
int[] counter = new int[1]; // <-- A bit of a kludge really.
return IntStream.range(0, s.length()).mapToObj(i -> {
    switch (Character.toLowerCase(s.charAt(i))) {
    case 'a': case 'e': case 'i': case 'o': case 'u':
        return Character.toString(vowels.charAt(counter[0]++));
    default:
        return Character.toString(s.charAt(i));
    }
}).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

Comment: seems to work OK for most but not for `System.out.println(reverseVowels("scarywombat"));`

Comment: @ScaryWombat "aoa"... :)